# Non-English characters in a Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, non-english

In my form, I have several labels with non English characters such as `ı`, `ş`, `ç`. They are displayed correctly in form design but when it is compiled and run, totally different characters are displayed. I have other projects developed in the same environment and never had an issue. What can cause this? I am working on VS2015.

Comment: Does changing the language of the form work for you? Check out this link-https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=174

Comment: An even better tutorial here:https://www.studentcompanion.co.za/creating-multilingual-applications-with-c/

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution while messing around. For anyone who encounters this in futurue:

Project Properties > Application > Assembly Information > Neutral Language

I changed this to the language I'm developing the application for and this did the trick. Though I never had to change this setting before.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Maybe you can mark this as an answer.